# dataTransform не получает значение с формы

Tags: php, symfony

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании dataTransformer.
Мне надо обработать получаемое значение с формы. По мануалу организовал следующим образом, но он оказался не рабочим -в трансформер приходит null

```
$arrayOfChoices = $this->getChoicesElements();
$builder->setMethod('GET');
$builder
->add('some_choice', ChoiceType::class, [
   'choices' => $arrayOfChoices,
   'placeholder' => ' ',
   'required' => false, ])
 ->add('some_text_1', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
 ->add('some_text_2', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
 ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
 ->setDataMapper($this);
 $builder->get('some_text_2')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
```

Comment: Вы создавали IssueToNumberTransformer ?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk, Да.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась банальной - я ожидал вызова метода transform в dataTransform, но вызывался метод revertTransform.